# Image Processing method for spiky selection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d

I have an input as **a 3D binary image** and the preferred output below:

Input:

[image: INPUT]

Preferred Output:

[image: OUTPUT]

What image processing methods should I look for if I am to have only the spiky object(s) remain, just like the preferred output above?

Comment: What do you mean by *3D binary* image? Can you easily segment the image into individual parts?

Comment: By 3D, I mean It's a tomographical image.

Comment: Can you explain what is `spiky` object? What really calls it spiky? what are the key characteristics to spot spiky objects?

Comment: A spiky object in this case is a 3D area that is not smooth and has these thorn like shapes all over them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are more corners on the borders of your "spiky object", so one approach would be to tune a [corner detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection) for this.

For example, I calculated the determinant of the structure tensor (Mathematica code below) of a distance-transformed image:

[image]

Binarizing with hysteresis yields this image, which should be a good starting point for the segmentation algorithm of your choice:

[image]

Mathematica code (`src` is the source image you posted)

At first, i calculate a distance transform of the input image. This creates contrasts over the whole object area (instead of just the border), so the whole object can be detected.

```
dist = ImageData[DistanceTransform[src]];
```

Next I prepare the components of the [structure tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor). The filter size for the gaussian derivatives if 5, the window size is 20.

```
gx = GaussianFilter[dist, 5, {1, 0}];
gy = GaussianFilter[dist, 5, {0, 1}];
gx2 = GaussianFilter[gx^2, 20];
gxy = GaussianFilter[gx*gy, 20];
gy2 = GaussianFilter[gy^2, 20];
```

To calculate the corner filter at each pixel, I simply plug these into the symbolic determinant of the structure tensor:

```
corners = Det[{{dx2, dxy}, {dxy, dy2}}] /. {dx2 -> gx2, dxy -> gxy, dy2 -> gy2};
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
corners = gx2 * gy2 - gxy * gxy;
```

Converting this to an image and scaling it to 0..1 range yields the corner detector image above.

Finally, binarizing it with the right thresholds gives the final, binary image:

```
MorphologicalBinarize[Image[corners], {0.025, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Very cool answer! = )

Comment: Your answers are amazing, I learn a lot from them.